# How to proceed with iOS set up without Wi-Fi network?

Tags: iphone, wifi, ios

I have just restored my iPhone 4 to iOS 5 factory settings but it requires a Wi-Fi network although I do not have a wireless access point in or around my house.

Can I not use the iOS 5 without a Wi-Fi connection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, set it as a new iPhone or restore your contents from iTunes backup in your computer by tethering your iPhone with iTunes.

Comment: It makes no difference. I still have to go through the same steps in my iPhone after setting as a new iPhone on iTunes. And the "restore from backup" option is telling that a session could not be started for some reason.

Comment: Is it because I am using an IPSW file rather than downloading it through iTunes?